Jetpack Compose launcher app launching animation
I am developing a launcher in jetpack compose and when I try to launch app it has default horizontal slide in animation which I'd like to change. I tried makeCustomAnimation(this@Activity, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out), but it has no difference and ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation requires a view which I have no idea how to provide since this is a jetpack compose.
What are my options to have semi-okayish animation where Icon scales up as supposed to and not just blank screen for 3 seconds?
